# KendoChart customizing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like to pass a Kendochart data and also adapt the valueAxis max value to my data . Furthermore, I would like to modify the CategoryAxis. The aim is to get a monthly Overview with for each day a value. An example the 1.08.2016 has 8 Hours, the second has 8 Hours. The CategoryAxis should be like: "Monday 1." "Thuesday 2." and so on.

Hope you can help me

Comment: You should share with us what you have tried so far and describe more detailed what your problem is.

Comment: i use KendoGrid very often and all works so i know the basics, but i don't know how to use KendoChart.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: if you're able to do kendo grid, at least you must be capable to post some code here bro